# How can I tell what libraries I need to Import? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, import, libraries

I am a complete newbie to Android development and it seems like every time I need some packet of functionality in my activity.java files I get the "Cannot find symbol" error and I need to import another library.

I have found that one, People tend to leave this out when answering questions on StackOverflow and two, that sometimes it is hard to find out what library to import.

I was wondering is there is any easy way to find out what it is I need to import based on the function or object that is the symbol that cannot be found.

For example the following code without "import android.widget.Toast;" would return an error:

```
String clicked = "String";

Toast.makeText(this, clicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
```

Comment: When you create a new android project the wizard takes care of importing the necessary libraries for you. Although the "cannot find symbol doesn't seem like a library problem. Could you please describe exactly what prroblem you are facing?

Comment: Post your code of what you are trying to import. You need to know what classes you are using, most likely from the Android docs. Android Studio and auto import imports: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/optimizing-imports.html

Comment: I found that the current issue I am running into is something different that what I have posted, I tested Black Bird's answer with another one I ran into earlier and it worked perfectly. The example being that I wanted to use Toast and I got "Cannot find symbol" and couldn't immediately tell what library I needed to import because I am a newbie, but pressing Alt + Enter while over that line where there is an error suggested the library and fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing Alt + Enter will automatically import some of your libraries or fix your errors. Otherwise it will just become muscle memory to remember what you are programming and what files you should import.

> Alt + Enter key binding
>
> For quick fixes to coding errors, the IntelliJ powered IDE implements the Alt + Enter key binding to fix errors (missing imports, variable assignments, missing references, etc) when possible, and if not, suggest the most probable solution.

- [**Android Studio Tips and Tricks**](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html)